# Apple Mail: Turn off new email notifications on Dock icon

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I have an email account that is set up to send an email every time someone sends a form. I keep it as a separate mailbox, but still in my inbox. I get the little red circle with a number in it when a new message come up but I get it confused with my normal email. Is there anyway to turn off email notifications for just 1 account?

[image: What it looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a mail rule that marks all messages received by that account as read. If you move or delete these emails after processing them, all in the inbox are actually unprocessed.

If this isn't enough, you could flag or add color to emails you still need to process, i.e. replacing the *unread* state by something else that doesn't count toward the number of unread emails.

Answer (score 0):

In account settings you can disable automatic checking of that mailbox.  Then it will only show a counter when you choose the mailbox and retrieve messages.